# FQL: retrieve objects from stream table that user liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

As described in the sample on documents, we can retrieve the user's news feed as below.
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id in (SELECT target_id FROM connection WHERE source_id= AND is_following=1) AND is_hidden = 0

What I want to do is to display user's news feed and when user clicks "my favorite", display the summary(all posts that a user liked).

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this criteria to your query  AND likes.user_likes = 1
and you should get it.
From example i do this to get all that i have liked in my wall:
https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT post_id, message, likes FROM stream WHERE source_id =  AND likes.user_likes = 1 limit 50&access_token=

The same applies to the above.

Comment: Thanks, Balakrishnan. Now I can get posts that a user likes. The new problem is taht even when I set "LIMIT 200", I only get few record. It looks like I'm getting liked posts **from** 200 latest posts.